# Collecting data from multiple radio button groups in Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have master-detail layout. Master flow is implemented using list fragment, and detail fragment is just radio button group. The layout looks like that:

[image: my layout]

For each option in list fragment there is a corresponding detail fragment with radio button group. What I want is to collect all checked (selected) radio button when `submit` button is clicked. Ideally I would like something like an array of checked radio buttons.

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest posting some relevant code you have already. This question doesn't show you have made some effort to achieve this.

Comment: I am not asking for code solution, but the direction to go. I have not implemented this part yet. I have the interface above implemented and I am thinking about approach to my current problem. That is why I asked what would be good approach (architecture) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I used ViewPager for detail view. ViewPager contains a radio button group. At each selection of radio button in the radio button group I record the choice to a static array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use hashmap to add selected option with key and value pair, when radio button is checked

```
Map<String, String> mapoption=new HashMap<String, String>();

if(rboption1.isChecked()){
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 1 selected");

        optionselect=1;
        mapoption.put(String.valueOf(rank), String.valueOf(optionselect));
    }
else if(rboption2.isChecked()){
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 2 selected");
        optionselect=2;
        mapoption.put(String.valueOf(rank), String.valueOf(optionselect));

    } else if(rboption3.isChecked()){
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 3 selected");
        optionselect=3;
        mapoption.put(String.valueOf(rank), String.valueOf(optionselect));

    }

    else if(rboption4.isChecked()) {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "option 4 selected");
        optionselect=4;
        mapoption.put(String.valueOf(rank), String.valueOf(optionselect));

    } else {
        Log.v(TAG+".onClick", "No any option is selected");
        optionselect=0;
        mapoption.put(String.valueOf(rank), String.valueOf(optionselect));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st how about using a check box for using multiple selection rather than Radio Button

2nd Take the view which contains all the Radion buttons that you have and iterate though like this and find the Radio buttons that are checked and add it to a list

```
RadioGroup rb = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
    ArrayList<RadioButton> list = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

    int childcount = rb.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
          View v = rb.getChildAt(i);
          if(v instanceof  RadioButton)
              if(((RadioButton)v).isChecked())
              list.add((RadioButton)v);
    }
```